# React ErrorBoundary doesn't catch "cannot read properties of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, exception, undefined, undefined-reference, react-error-boundary

I faced a weird edge case with React [ErrorBoundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html). Exceptions are not being processed if they happen in inline expression. For example:

```
const page = webtexts[courseId].pages[pageFamilyId]; // Returns undefined
...
<ErrorBoundary>
    // "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'page_name')" won't be processed in ErrorBoundary
    <span>{page.page_name}</span>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

But if I wrap a problematic place in the component, it works properly.

```
const page = webtexts[courseId].pages[pageFamilyId]; // Returns undefined
...
const WrapFailingPage: React.FC<{ page: any }> = ({ page }) => {
    return <span>{page.page_name}</span>;
};
...
<ErrorBoundary>
    <WrapFailingPage page={page} /> // The error is properly processed in ErrorBoundary
</ErrorBoundary>
```

For the demo, I made a simple Codepen - https://codepen.io/OlexanderD/pen/wvpdpxY.

Should the `ErrorBoundary` behave in that way? Why the inline expressions can be problematic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

`ErrorBoundary` tracks only the code parts that were created with `React.createElement(React.Component / React.[V]FC)`. Therefore, if you return a broken JSX from a custom React component, `ErrorBoundary` will pick it up and process.

#### Details:

###### Examples are made for the attached Codepen https://codepen.io/OlexanderD/pen/wvpdpxY

A bit of terminology:

- `element` - any HTML tag. It'll be processed as `React.createElement('div', ...)`
- `component` - any React component, not native HTML tag. I'll be processed as  `React.createElement(MyComponent, ...)`

According to [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#:%7E:text=catch%20JavaScript%20errors%20anywhere%20in%20their%20child%20component%20tree), `ErrorBoundary` can process exceptions only *in their child **component** tree*, but I tried to catch an exception from the **element**.

[React.createElement()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) can receives 2 types of arguments: *tag name* (`div`, `span`, ...) or *React component*. Therefore, when we simply use `<div>{fail.absurdIntentionalError}</div>` and pass it to parent `div` the React will generate [this code](http://surl.li/bqeso):

```
React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  React.createElement("button", ...),
  showFailingChild &&
  React.createElement("div", null, fail.absurdIntentionalError)
);
```

As you can see we're passing an ***element*** as the part of the `props.children` for the parent `div`. Therefore the *`ErrorBoundary` won't process* it as the part of the ***component** tree*.

But if we use some wrapper like `FailingComponent`, the generated JSX will look [like this](http://surl.li/bqeur):

```
React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  React.createElement("button", ...),
  showFailingComponent &&
  React.createElement(FailingComponent, null)
);
```

Now we're passing the **component** to the `props.children` for the parent `div`. And the `ErrorBoundary` will process the result of the `FailingComponent` as the part of the ***component** tree*.

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes when you have not initiated Bugsnag correctly.

Here is an example **that triggers** an error:

```
    import Bugsnag from '@bugsnag/js';

    const bugsnagClient = Bugsnag.start({
    apiKey: 'my-bugsnag-api-key',
    // plugins: [new BugsnagPluginReact()], <----- assume not there
   releaseStage: 'production',
   });

    const ErrorBoundary = 
    Bugsnag.getPlugin('react').createErrorBoundary(React)

    <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorView}>
    <App store={store} />
    </ErrorBoundary>
```

The above will trigger the "React ErrorBoundary doesn't catch "cannot read properties of undefined" error.
Therefore, in this case including that code will fix the issue as below:

```
    import Bugsnag from '@bugsnag/js';
    import BugsnagPluginReact from '@bugsnag/plugin-react'; // <----- inserted here

    const bugsnagClient = Bugsnag.start({
    apiKey: 'my-bugsnag-api-key',
    plugins: [new BugsnagPluginReact()], // <----- inserted here
   releaseStage: 'production',
   });
```