# Expo - React Native App HostFunction/ErrorBoundary errors while bundling

Tags: react-native, expo, android-emulator, react-error-boundary

i've been encountering multiples errors like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d66Ze.png) and [That](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBmpj.png) when bundling my expo app on an emulator.

I've been searching for several days for a solution, and even if the errors can be found probably similarly (like here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646690/react-errorboundary-doesnt-catch-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined](https://stackoverflow.com)) none of the solutions i've found for thoses errors actually works. I'm out of existing solutions on that one...

I've tried clearing cache, reinstalling all the project, deleting node_modules and reinstalling, i've verified every version of my dependencies, looked for every Github Issues for what i'm using to see if someone already got the same and found a solution, but nothing.

For instance it's an Expo app using Tamagui, React Native and Typescript, with Supabase